# ASP gets error onload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building an ASP site using GoDaddy with ASP version 4.6.2. I am building using ASP 4.5.1. I have a security policy of

```
 <system.web>
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal" />
</securityPolicy> </system.web>
```

> The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
>   security policy. To grant this application the required permission
>   please contact your system administrator or change the application's
>   trust level in the configuration file. [SecurityException: Request
>   failed.]
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly
>   asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +166
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object
>   assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +100
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet
>   grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString,
>   SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +272
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack
>   cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet
>   demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, RuntimeAssembly asm,
>   SecurityAction action) +55
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName) +70    System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +39
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +32
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid()
>   +10    System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection
>   ps) +2085
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash()
>   +107    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64
>   cachedHash) +465
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64
>   cachedHash) +51
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +132
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

Is there something I can look at as I'm not sure where the error message is pointing. Or do I need to contact GoDaddy?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you accessing any disk files for storing/logging etc. In that case try to get write permission for that folder and try again. May be one possible problem that I can guess.

Comment: i figured it out.
In plesk i go Manage->ASP.NET settings->CAS trust level=Full
In my Web.config I have 
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>